# Loop is not working C#.net

Tags: c#

My miniproject is in C#.net and my project is a windowsform quiz application. There is two user in my app, 'admin' and a 'user'. Admin can delete and add questions.

**My problem is** when admin delete a question from the middle I want to rearrange the question numbers. Because questions are randomly selected according to their question number. I am using a while loop. The loop is executing but the updating command is not working. Any one suggest another loop or another method to select questions randomly.

Here is my code in delete button:

```
private void button_DELQUE_DELETE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //deleting questions and options
    CMD = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM QUESTIONS WHERE NO='" +int.Parse(    textBox_DELQUE_NO.Text).ToString() + "'", CNN);
    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CMD = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM OPTIONS WHERE NO='" +    int.Parse(textBox_DELQUE_NO.Text).ToString() + "'", CNN);
    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int TOT = 0;
    CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QUESTIONS", CNN);
    TOT = int.Parse(CMD.ExecuteScalar().ToString());//total no.of questions after deletion
    int I = 0;
    int DEL = 0;
    int TEMP = 0;
    DEL = int.Parse(textBox_DELQUE_NO.Text.ToString());//deleted question
    TEMP = DEL;

    while (TEMP == TOT)
    {
        I = TEMP;
        I = I + 1;
        CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE QUESTIONS SET NO='" + I + "' WHERE NO='" +   TEMP + "'", CNN);
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OPTIONS SET NO='" + I + "' WHERE NO='" + TEMP  + "'", CNN);
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TEMP = TEMP + 1;

    }
```

Comment: DO you want to update all records when you delete one of them? Can I suggest to change that? Actually you **don't need** it, question should be what you'll use it for...

Comment: It took sometime for me to realize this is C# code. Please follow [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is quite a bit "wrong" with the code (aside from the issue at hand). It hurts my head to look at it as I've not seen so many violations of best practices since before we fired that Jr. guy some years ago... ;-)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes.Or there is any other way to select questions randomly

Comment: @Kannan of course there is, you can order them by...a random generated number. In your case I assume you don't have a huge table and you don't require _good_ random numbers then simply `SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY newid()` will work. Add `TOP n` to extract only `n` rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just update all after the `id` that was removed? Like that you don't need a `while`, and performance will go up 300%.

```
update questions set no = no - 1 where no > @yourRemovedID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a couple of issues here. First is that you have:

```cs
while (TEMP == TOT)
{
    ...
    TEMP = TEMP + 1;
}
```

This will at most only every execute once. This seems like a bad loop. Second, you are:

```
CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE QUESTIONS SET NO='" + I + "' WHERE NO='" +   TEMP + "'", CNN);
TEMP = TEMP + 1;
```

If your loop ever executed more than once (like if it was a for/foreach) then you would constantly be updating the same records. You just increased the number "I" to +1 which is what TEMP is now. So your new record will be in the where clause.

I would consider rethinking this logic. If you only want it to execute once, change it from a `while` to a `if`, it will make more sense to anyone that looks at it. It doesn't look like you are actually "rearranging" the numbers. You are just shifting the numbers to compensate for the one that was removed. Is that what you mean or did you mean to say that you wanted all of them in a new random order? If it is the first, then @Patrick's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I mean if there is 5 questions then the question numbers are 1,2,3,4,5. And if i delet 3rd question then the numbers should be in 1=1,2=2,4=3,5=4.

Comment: So, then the former where you are just shifting the numbers down to compensate for the removed one. Go with @Patrick's answer for your SQL, but you still need to rework your logic.

Comment: This could probably all be put into one stored procedure instead of mixed between code and hardcoded sql.